# Gain plot using seaborn - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am generating gain plot based on the following example data in `Matplotlib`.

```
M_GRP_1      F_GRP_1    GRP_1       GAIN_GRP_1
0.036796    0.067024    0.058878    0.624948
0.000093    0.000087    0.000089    1.043674
0.000316    0.0002      0.000231    1.366149
0.011152    0.008329    0.00909      1.226813
0.001227    0.000747    0.000876    1.400792



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches([18, 9])
ax.plot(np.linspace(0,1),np.linspace(0,1), color = 'black', linewidth = 2)
D = d.sort_values('GRP_1', ascending = False).cumsum() 
ax.plot(D.iloc[:,2], D.iloc[:,0], color = 'orange', linewidth = 2)
plt.xlabel('Percentage of total data')
plt.ylabel('Gain')
plt.title ('Target groups :: GRP_1')
plt.legend(['Basline','Male'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

However, I want to generate same plot using `seaborn`. I am wondering how I can do that as I,m not familiar with it.

Can any body suggest/help with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn is based on matplotlib, so most of your code is the same.
Just `import seaborn as sns` and replace `ax.plot` by `sns.lineplot`.

You may also want to add `sns.set_theme()` (or `sns.set()` prior to version 0.11.0) to apply seaborn default styles.